# How can I load a two level route?

Tags: ember.js

I would like to load a route that look like this :

catalog/category

I have tried so far multiple things like the following :

Template:

```
{{#link-to "catalog/category" tagName="li" href=false}}Catalog{{/link-to}}
```

App.js

```
this.resource('catalog/category', function() {
    this.resource('add', {path: 'add'});        
});
```

Without much success!

What am I doing wrong ?
Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For nested resources, try

```
{{#link-to "catalog.category" tagName="li" href=false}}Catalog{{/link-to}}
```

and (assuming that you have a parent resource of catalog):

```
this.resource('catalog.category', ...
```

You can see examples within the documentation, here: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_nested-resources